# What's the average speed (along $z$) and the average position (along $z$) of an object in free fall?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, free-fall

I'm looking to calculate the average speed (along z) and the average position (along z) of an object in free fall.

The initial instant is $t_0$ and we have:

- $z(t=t_0)=z_0$
- $v_z(t=t_0)=v_0=0$

I calculated the final instant, the instant at which the object hits the ground, and I found that: $$t_f = \sqrt{ \dfrac{2 z_0}{g} }$$

For the average position along $z$ I found that : $$<z> = \int (- \frac{1}{2} g t^2 + z_0) dt = z_0^{\frac{3}{2}} \dfrac{3}{2} \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{g}}$$

For the average speed along $z$ I found that : $$<v_z> = \int (-gt) dt = - z_0$$

Both expressions are not enough homogeneous, so they're both completely wrong...

Comment: Your average $<z>$ is simple $\frac{z_0+z_f}{2}$ and $<v>=\frac{v_0+v_f}{2}$ where $f$ stands for 'final' or 'end'. No point wasting integrals on it.

Comment: @Gert: Not true for the average z, since z grows as $t^2$. Maybe $<z>=\frac{2}{3}z_0$ but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: Your integral $<z> = \int (- \frac{1}{2} g t^2 + z_0) dt$ only gives you $z$ after time $t$, not an expectation value. You need to divide that by total travel time. Similarly, $<v_z> = \int (-gt) dt$ only gives you $v$ after time $t$, not an average speed. It's also easier to set $z_0=0$.  The integrals also lack boundaries.

Comment: In fact: $z(t) =z_0 + \int_0^t (- \frac{1}{2} g t^2) dt$

Comment: The OP question doesn't tend to make sense.  If you have position and velocity as functions of time, why in the world would you want to destroy all that information by asking what the average values of these variables are?

Answer (score 1):

So we have a $z$ axis pointing upwards and a object in free fall from $z=z_0$ to $z=0$.

The equation of motion in free fall is $-ma=mg$ or $a=-g$.

$\large{a=\frac{dv}{dt}}$.

$dv=-gdt$ and integrated we get:

$v=\int_0^t(-g)dt=-gt$.

$v=\frac{dz}{dt}$, so $dz=vdt$, $dz=-gtdt$ and integrated we get:

$z=z_0-\frac{gt^2}{2}$.

For $z=0$, $0=z_0-\frac{gt_f^2}{2}$ and $t_f=\sqrt{\frac{2z_0}{g}}$.

So that $v_f=-g\sqrt{\frac{2z_0}{g}}=-\sqrt{2z_0g}$.

The average speed over time is:

$\Large{<v>=\frac{\int_0^{t_f} vdt}{(t_f -0)}=-\frac{\sqrt{2z_0g}}{2}}$.

The average position over time is:

$<z>=\frac{\int_0^{t_f} zdt}{(t_f -0)}$.

With $\int_0^{t_f} zdt= \int_0^{t_f}(z_0-\frac{dt^2}{2})dt=z_0t_f-\frac{gt_f^3}{6}$.

Divide by $t_f$ to get:

$<z>=z_0-\frac{gt_f^2}{6}$, insert $t_f=\sqrt{\frac{2z_0}{g}}$ and rework to get:

$\Large{<z>=\frac{2}{3} z_0}$.